# Unhandled error in mscorlib System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, mscorlib

I have an .aspx, suddenly it doesn't load.. checkin the results tabs found this:

> Primera excepción del tipo 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' en mscorlib.dll
> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' en mscorlib.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

> Primera excepción del tipo 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' en mscorlib.dll
> Primera excepción del tipo 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' en App_Web_3fxd1sxq.dll

Facts:

1. I'm already using: Response.Redirect("url",false);
2. Also using: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
3. I'm working on vmware with windows7 ultimate (x32).
4. Visual Studio 2012
5. the app is on .net framework v. 4

Comment: I have already "repair" visual studio 2012.. nothing happens :/

Comment: Does it still throws exception if you create a ***new*** ASP.Net Empty Web Application with a single aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the IIS app pool recycles your application.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't happen on production, it happens when debuggin